# Always empty response with $.getJSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a simple web service that outputs a JSON object to a client.

If accessed with a plain browser it outputs the JSON string. However when accessed with `$.getJSON` it always return a empty response although there is a response header:

```
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  122
Connection  keep-alive
```

The code for the call is like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.0.1/api/v1/search', { query : $('#searchfield').val() }, 
    function(data){
        $.log("Response: %s", data.some_field);     
    }
);
```

Also the callback function is not invoked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Verify that the response is indeed proper JSON (http://jsonlint.com/) or else getJSON will barf.

Comment: Is it a different server than the page was served from? If yes, the request is subject to the same-origin policy.

Comment: @FelixKling if so, wouldn't there *not* be a response header via `$.getJSON`?

Comment: @xybrek can you create a jsfiddle for this problem?

Comment: @Chantz, sure, however I am not familiar with jsFiddle. Also I am not sure if $.log will work since I used another js library for that?

Comment: @FelixKling, yah, if this is SOP, would I still get response header?

Comment: Well, you should know whether it is the same host or not. If it is then no, the problem lies elsewhere. If it is a different host, then this is your problem.

Comment: @xybrek $.log is just a print state,ent/ You can use alert("some string"); for the sake of the example. jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/

Comment: @Chantz I am trying to do jsfiddle, but it won't respond when I click run. Do I need to signup before I can test it?

Comment: @xybrek. Nope it is a free service. First just print a simple alert and see if that shows up.